# How to log in to twitter without Oauth for a script?

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, oauth

To use OAUTH with python-twitter I need to register a web app, website etc. The program I have is for personal use though. Since basic auth is now defunct and Oauth is not an option due to the requirements is there a work around to log in to twitter using a script?

I can't imagine that Twitter would alienate everyone who does not have a website/web app from logging in to twitter from a script that is for personal use.

Comment: Why are the requirements that you can't use OAuth if it's for personal use?  P.S. Pretty sure OAuth or @Anywhere is the only way to go.

Comment: Thank you for replying impluse3d. If I understand this issue correctly, to use Oauth you need to register an app to receive the requisite keys. I do not have a website/web app or plan on creating one. Perhaps I have misunderstood Oauth, but this is the only way as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

If you register your Twitter app as a "Client" app instead of a "Browser" (aka web) app, you can create an application without the need for a live web app.  (Note: you'll still have to store an OAuth key.)

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-oauth1/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw97OAuth-Twitter) is a down-and-dirty resource for how it all works and how to accomplish this.

Edit: maybe something like [this](http://simpleauthtwitter.heroku.com/) can help you if you're just looking to fill out a quick personal project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access resources at Twitter, even if they are your own, and even if it is just for a "personal script" -> you have to use oAuth.